# Python safe string compression without line breaks

Tags: python, compression, zlib

I am trying to save a large amount of JSON files, by appending the JSON string as a new line to a large text file. I have limited storage so I don't want to save the JSON string as is for so many files. Instead, I try to compress the JSON string using zlib library, and then append the compressed string as a new line to the big file.

The compression is pretty good, however the problem is that it often happens that the compressed string contains a line break character "\n", which causes error for decompression when reading line by line.
I tried to overcome this problem by using base64 encoding for the zlib compressed string, since bas64 does not have line breaks, but it causes the final string to be much longer and hence the compression is less effective (actually for shorter strings, the final string after zlib/base64 is longer than the original string).

```
import zlib, base64
item_dict={}
item_dict["a"]="ما هذا الذي قاله اليوم بشأن الأخبارية التي فلتها متعمدا؟"
item_dict["b"]="She’s allowed to not want someone else’s kids in her picture. Y’all are weird for the way youre acting over this. I don’t want any pics of myself with my ex’s children, because they aren’t my children and I’m not in their lives anymore. It’s weird to post pics of someone else’s kids… so asking for them to be removed so I can still enjoy my picture from my holiday isn’t as bad as y’all are making it seem."
item_dict["c"]='''
{"symbol": "A/RES/74/1", "resolution_number": "74/1.", "title": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations: requests under Article 19 of the Charter", "session": "Seventy-fourth session", "adoption_meeting": "14th plenary meeting", "adoption_date": "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "originating_document": "A/74/483", "report_paragraph": "6", "committee": "Fifth Committee", "agenda_item": "Agenda item 139", "agenda_item_name": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations", "voting_type": "Without a vote", "MS_in_favour_count": "N.A.", "MS_against_count": "N.A.", "MS_abstaining_count": "N.A.", "pv": "A/74/PV.14", "MS_in_favour": [], "MS_against": [], "MS_abstaining": [], "sponsors": ["SUBMITTED BY THE CHAIR OF THE COMMITTEE"], "additional_sponsors": [], "SDGs": [], "subjects": [["Comoros", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Sao Tome And Principe", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Somalia", "UNBIS Thesaurus"]]}
{"symbol": "A/RES/74/2", "resolution_number": "74/2.", "title": "Political declaration of the high-level meeting on universal health coverage", "session": "Seventy-fourth session", "adoption_meeting": "14th plenary meeting", "adoption_date": "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "originating_document": "A/74/L.4", "report_paragraph": "N.A.", "committee": "Without reference to a Main Committee", "agenda_item": "Agenda item 126", "agenda_item_name": "Global health and foreign policy", "voting_type": "Without a vote", "MS_in_favour_count": "N.A.", "MS_against_count": "N.A.", "MS_abstaining_count": "N.A.", "pv": "A/74/PV.14", "MS_in_favour": [], "MS_against": [], "MS_abstaining": [], "sponsors": ["SUBMITTED BY THE PRESIDENT OF THE GENERAL ASSEMBLY"], "additional_sponsors": [], "SDGs": ["3"], "subjects": [["Health Policy", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Public Health", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Health Services", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Health Insurance", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Declarations (Text)", "UNBIS Thesaurus"]]}
{"symbol": "A/RES/74/3", "resolution_number": "74/3.", "title": "Political declaration of the high-level meeting to review progress made in addressing the priorities of small island developing States through the implementation of the SIDS Accelerated Modalities of Action (SAMOA) Pathway", "session": "Seventy-fourth session", "adoption_meeting": "14th plenary meeting", "adoption_date": "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "originating_document": "A/74/L.3", "report_paragraph": "N.A.", "committee": "Without reference to a Main Committee", "agenda_item": "Agenda item 19 (b)", "agenda_item_name": "Sustainable development: follow-up to and implementation of the SIDS Accelerated Modalities of Action (SAMOA) Pathway and the Mauritius Strategy for the Further Implementation of the Programme of Action for the Sustainable Development of Small Island Developing States of the SIDS Accelerated Modalities of Action (SAMOA) Pathway and the Mauritius Strategy for the Further Implementation of the Programme of Action for the Sustainable Development of Small Island Developing States", "voting_type": "Without a vote", "MS_in_favour_count": "N.A.", "MS_against_count": "N.A.", "MS_abstaining_count": "N.A.", "pv": "A/74/PV.14", "MS_in_favour": [], "MS_against": [], "MS_abstaining": [], "sponsors": ["SUBMITTED BY THE PRESIDENT OF THE GENERAL ASSEMBLY"], "additional_sponsors": [], "SDGs": ["16", "17", "3"], "subjects": [["Sustainable Development", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Developing Island Countries", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Development Assistance", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Programme Implementation", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Programme Evaluation", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Declarations (Text)", "UNBIS Thesaurus"]]}
'''
item_dict["d"]='{"url": "http://agribank.ngan-hang.net", "final_url": "http://ww7.ngan-hang.net/?usid=18&utid=23776691570", "lang": "", "title": "", "description": "", "keywords": "", "phone_numbers": [], "links": [], "social_links": [], "emails": [], "addresses": [], "logos": [], "text": "", "last": 41, "n_items": 1}'
for key,val in item_dict.items():
  zlib_compressed=zlib.compress(val.encode())
  base64_compressed=base64.b64encode(zlib_compressed)
  zlib_n_line_breaks=zlib_compressed.count(b'\n')
  base64_line_breaks=base64_compressed.count(b'\n')
  print("original size:",len(val)," | zlib:",len(zlib_compressed),"base64",len(base64_compressed),"| zlib_n_line_breaks",zlib_n_line_breaks,base64_line_breaks)
```

Result:

```
original size: 56  | zlib: 84 base64 112 | zlib_n_line_breaks 0 0
original size: 407  | zlib: 254 base64 340 | zlib_n_line_breaks 0 0
original size: 3655  | zlib: 941 base64 1256 | zlib_n_line_breaks 1 0
original size: 303  | zlib: 184 base64 248 | zlib_n_line_breaks 1 0
```

As a work around, I created a custom compression/decompression function, that replaces the line break in compression with an arbitrary string (e.g. 00000), and in the decompression it does the opposite. This reduces the likelihood of decompression errors but does not eliminate it, because it can happen that the original compressed string has this arbitrary string somehow.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585234/can-zlib-compressed-output-avoid-using-certain-byte-value), not satisfactory though:

So, the question here is the following -
Is there any compression algorithm that can compress a string without producing a line break? Or is there a way to reliably post-process zlib compression/decompression output (or the output of any compression algorithm) to avoid line breaks?

## Edit

Thanks to the answer by Booboo, I realized the difference between a line break character and a slash followed by "n", and I tested it and it now makes sense for the encoding part:

```
import zlib
line0='{"symbol": "A/RES/74/1", "resolution_number": "74/1.", "title": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations: requests under Article 19 of the Charter", "session": "Seventy-fourth session", "adoption_meeting": "14th plenary meeting", "adoption_date": "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "originating_document": "A/74/483", "report_paragraph": "6", "committee": "Fifth Committee", "agenda_item": "Agenda item 139", "agenda_item_name": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations", "voting_type": "Without a vote", "MS_in_favour_count": "N.A.", "MS_against_count": "N.A.", "MS_abstaining_count": "N.A.", "pv": "A/74/PV.14", "MS_in_favour": [], "MS_against": [], "MS_abstaining": [], "sponsors": ["SUBMITTED BY THE CHAIR OF THE COMMITTEE"], "additional_sponsors": [], "SDGs": [], "subjects": [["Comoros", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Sao Tome And Principe", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Somalia", "UNBIS Thesaurus"]]} {"url": "http://agroreal911.sk", "final_url": "http://agroreal911.sk/", "lang": "sk-SK", "title": "Agroreal 911 s.r.o.", "description": "", "keywords": "", "phone_numbers": [], "links": [["http://agroreal911.sk/pozemky", "K\u00fapa p\u00f4dy"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/kontakty", "Kontakty"], ["http://www.advertplus.sk", "Advertplus.sk"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/predaj-pody", "Predaj p\u00f4dy"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/o-nas", "O n\u00e1s"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/?lang=en", ""], ["http://transposh.org/sk", ""]], "social_links": [], "emails": ["mgr.michal.hrabovsky@gmail.com"], "addresses": [], "logos": ["http://agroreal911.sk/wp-content/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/img/tplogo.png"], "text": "Agroreal 911 s.r.o. \nAGRO REAL 911,  S.R.O. \nMenu \nO n\u00e1s \nPOZEMKY \nK\u00fapa p\u00f4dy \nPredaj p\u00f4dy \nKontakty \nby  \nWebstr\u00e1nku vytvoril  Advertplus.sk Kontakt:   0908 692 782 \u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\n\n\n \n   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n   mgr.michal.hrabovsky@gmail.com\n\n\n  ", "last": 74, "n_items": 2}'
compressed=zlib.compress(line0.encode())
compressed0=compressed.replace(b"\n",b"\\n")
print("number of line breaks in zlib output:", compressed.count(b"\n"))

test_out_fpath="test_compress.txt"
fopen0=open(test_out_fpath,"wb")
fopen0.write(compressed0)
fopen0.close()

fopen0=open(test_out_fpath,"rb")
lines=fopen0.readlines()
print("number of lines after replacing line breaks", len(lines))
fopen0.close()
```

**Output**

```
number of line breaks in zlib output: 7
number of lines after replacing line breaks 1
```

I'd still need help with the decompression though, if possible

Comment: If you have so much data you probably shouldn't be using JSON in the first place, use a database.

Comment: Don't write each value as a separate JSON string. Put everything into a list, convert that list to JSON and then compress it all.

Comment: Or, write each JSON object as a two-field record: the first a 4-byte value indication the length of the compressed object, then a variable-sized field containing the actual compressed object.

Comment: @Barmar I don't want to use a database, much of my work involves iterating over the lines of the file and identifying the last line of the file.
I also append the lines continuously, so I cannot just compress everything, because there will be more lines to be written later

Comment: What is not satisfactory about my answer to the linked question? It does exactly what you're asking for, which is to post-process the zlib (or any) output to eliminate line breaks.

Comment: @chepner this might be an actually good idea, but I still want to use the "readline" method, as I iterate line by line

Comment: @MarkAdler sorry didn't mean it this way :) Mainly the answer is not in python, and the replacement isn't very clear to me

Comment: You seem to be making things deliberately harder by trying to use `readline()` with non-textual data. It's for reading text files.

Comment: You can't do that: a text file is essentially a binary file with `0x0a` treated as a record terminator. The only way you can treat the file as a text file is if you use a compression scheme that is guaranteed to not use `0x0a` in its output.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using a text file that I'm reading and writing in binary, it still has the readline()

Comment: @chepner that's the main issue, to guarantee that the compressed string doesn't have a certain character

Comment: gzip output is not textual. Using text functions on a binary file doesn't make it a text file.

Comment: @Barmar of course

Comment: There's simply no completely safe way to do what you want. Anything you replace the newlines with could conceivably be in the actual compressed data. You're just setting yourself up for failure by restricting the way you process the file.

Comment: You can define your own file iterator type that has a `read_record` method that encapsulates the size/data handling.

Comment: @chepner I think this can be a good direction, can you please add an answer with this?

Comment: @Barmar the thing is that I'm doing it now reasonably enough with proper error handling, good compression overall and one error in like a million records, but I'm looking for something more solid

Comment: Yuor solution is probably as good as you can get. The longer you make the substitution, the less likely it will conflict with actual compressed data.

Comment: @Barmar What? No. There are absolutely many completely safe ways to do what he wants. A simple example would be to use an escape character followed by an `n` to mean a new line, and an escape character followed by an escape to mean an escape. That would be a completely lossless transformation that can be reversed. On average that would increase the size of the data by 0.8%. [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62598400/1180620) from the linked question increases the length by 0.07%.

Comment: @MarkAdler can you please add an answer with a python implementation? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: You can easily implement my suggestion in the comment yourself. Or the translation of the C code in the linked answer to Python is straightfoward. All the operators are the same in C and Python, except `++` in C is `+= 1` in Python.

Comment: @MarkAdler nope, it's so foreign to me, I don't understand what is unsigned, buf, getc and many other things :) it would be nice of course to learn C at some point, but for now I'd appreciate it if I can get an answer in python

Comment: Then just implement the escapes. Nothing could be simpler.

Comment: @MarkAdler not sure, you mean by escape this character "\"?

Comment: Any character you like. (Except a newline.) Sure, a backslash is a traditional escape character.

Comment: @MarkAdler I'm not sure I'm understanding you properly. In my data, it often happens that a backslash can be followed by another backslash, and any character can be followed by the same character

Comment: _Think about it._ If you replace every backslash with two backslashes, and every new line with a backslash and an `n`, then you can unambiguously reverse that on the other end. Yes, you may have two backslashes in the compressed data, but that gets converted into _four_ backslashes. On the other end it gets converted back to two backslashes.

Comment: @MarkAdler that starts to sound more reasonable, but I think we'll still run into the problem instead of having \n, we will have \\n, which doesn't fix the original issue. Would it be ok if you post an answer for easier discussion?

Comment: OMG, no. _Think about it!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the compressed `JSON` you should first replace every backslash (b'\\') with two backslashes (b'\\\\') and then replace a newline (b'\n') with a backslash followed by 'n' (b'\\n'). After writing out the compressed data you write out a newline (b'\n'). You can use the `str.replace` method for doing these replacements,

You reverse the operation by first doing a `readline` and then stripping out the trailing b'\n'). You then must look at each character *one by one* and if you see a backslash then if the next character is also a backslash, you replace the two backslashes with a single one. Otherwise, the next character must be a 'n' and you replace the two characters with a newline. Note that the results of doing a call to `readline` on a binary file is a `bytes` instance and when you iterate through this each element is an `int` in the range 0 through 255. So when you want to look for a backslash, for example, you should be comparing the element with `ord(b'\\')`, which converts a backslash character to its corresponding integer value.

**Update**

Read the docstrings in the following two functions:

```py
def replace_newlines(s: bytes) -> bytes:
    """Given a bytes instance consisting of a `JSON` string encoded
    to bytes and then compressed, replace backslash characters
    with two backslashes and newline characters with the
    two-character sequence of a backslash followed by 'n'."""

    return s.replace(b'\\', b'\\\\').replace(b'\n', b'\\n')

def restore_newlines(s: bytes) -> bytes:
    """Given a bytes instance that have had newline
    characters removed with function replace_newline, this function
    will restore the newline characters."""
    
    BACKSLASH = ord(b'\\')
    NEWLINE = ord(b'\n')

    output = []
    idx = 0
    lnth = len(s)
    while idx < lnth:
        if s[idx] != BACKSLASH:
            output.append(s[idx])
            idx += 1
        elif s[idx + 1] == BACKSLASH:
            output.append(BACKSLASH)
            idx += 2
        else:
            # next character must be b'n'
            output.append(NEWLINE)
            idx += 2
    return bytes(output)
```

**An Alternate `restore_newlines` Implementation**

```py
import re
...
def restore_newlines(s: bytes) -> bytes:
    """Given a bytes instance that have had newline
    characters removed with function replace_newline, this function
    will restore the newline characters."""

    # A backslash can only be followed by another backslash or 'n':
    return re.sub(br'\\(.)', lambda m: b'\\' if m[1] == b'\\' else b'\n', s)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a good direction, but still not very clear to me. I think the replacement should work, but if I replace '\n' with '\\n', still the line would break and I won't be able to use readline, how do we avoid that?

Comment: No! b'\n` is a single character whose integer value is 10 and b'\\n` are two characters, a backslash (integer 92) followed by an 'n' (integer 110). `b'\\n' does *not* contain a newline character,

Comment: I think this is the part I don't understand. I'm starting to see that you're making a distinction between the newline character, with an ord value of 10, and a slash followed by "n", which are two separate characters, but how do I write slash n in a line, without being interpreted as a line break by the readline command?

Comment: A backslash in a string represents the start of a special escape sequence whose meaning depends on the following character. For example, when followed by an 'n' as in '\n', it represents the single newline character; when followed by 'r' as in `\r' it represents a carriage-return character. Then how is a backslash to be entered in a string as just a backslash? Well, when a backslash is followed by another backslash as in '\\', then that special escape sequence represents a single backspace character. So a backslash followed by an 'n' is '\\n'.

Comment: See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences). There is no newline character in '\\n'. I have said before that this represents two distinct characters: a backslash character followed by 'n'. This is totally different than the single newline character represented with '\n'. I don't know how else to make this any clearer.

Comment: This is helpful, and apologies as I have been struggling with this concept. I updated the question with this replacement and now I can see that the line does not break this way, so I can read the compressed string as one line. Would it be possible to show me your implementation of the decompression step though? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: See update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I also posted an answer with my implementation, yours is more compact, I appreciate it

Comment: I have updated the answer with an alternate `restore_newlines` Implementation.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know you can do that with regex, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Read the input one character at a time, and replace every new line with a backslash and an `n`, and every backslash with two backslashes. Anything else, copy the character as is.

On the other end, reading one character at a time, if you see a backslash, look at the next byte. If it's an `n`, output a new line. Otherwise output a backslash. If it's not a backslash, output the character as is.

Comment: Ok, so we have a line like this after compression:
ad4324\n!dsfsd\nsdfsd\dsfsd\\fsdf
and I don't want to see any \n because it breaks the line. So, what exactly do I replace?

Comment: If you can show me a small implementation of this in python I'd really appreciate it, because I think there is something I don't understand about escape and new line characters

Comment: The code is right there, in English. Follow exactly what I wrote and all your questions will be answered. Write the encoder and decoder as I described. Then test it with long sequences of random bytes, checking that what you get out of the decoder is exactly what you put in the encoder.

Comment: Hah! A bounty to try to get other people to write your code for you. Stackoverflow is for programmers. You are expected to write your own code. If you write code, and you are having problems with it, _then_ post a new question _with your code that you wrote_, what you expected, and what happened instead.

Comment: Well my friend, I think I know what stackoverflow is :) I asked for a solution in python to this particular problem, I didn't get any so far, so I'm hoping to

Comment: It is sad that you are not willing to put in the effort.

Comment: I would suggest that you first replace a backslash with two backslashes and only then replace a newline with backslash followed by 'n'. In other words, I would change the order of replacements if you are going to be using `str.replace` for doing the replacements. And "on the other end" you need to iterate through each character one by one (you cannot use `str.replace`). Test with the input being a backslash followed by 'n' followed by a newline.

Comment: @Booboo What I wrote is to be applied to each character, one at a time. Either the input character is a backslash, or it's a new line. It can't be both. I have clarified the answer. There was nothing in the answer about using `str.replace`, which is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a way to do it, so here is my answer with my code implementation, hoping it would benefit someone looking for it in the future. It is based mainly on the answer by Booboo.

```
import zlib
line0='{"symbol": "A/RES/74/1", "resolution_number": "74/1.", "title": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations: requests under Article 19 of the Charter", "session": "Seventy-fourth session", "adoption_meeting": "14th plenary meeting", "adoption_date": "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "originating_document": "A/74/483", "report_paragraph": "6", "committee": "Fifth Committee", "agenda_item": "Agenda item 139", "agenda_item_name": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations", "voting_type": "Without a vote", "MS_in_favour_count": "N.A.", "MS_against_count": "N.A.", "MS_abstaining_count": "N.A.", "pv": "A/74/PV.14", "MS_in_favour": [], "MS_against": [], "MS_abstaining": [], "sponsors": ["SUBMITTED BY THE CHAIR OF THE COMMITTEE"], "additional_sponsors": [], "SDGs": [], "subjects": [["Comoros", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Sao Tome And Principe", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Somalia", "UNBIS Thesaurus"]]} {"url": "http://agroreal911.sk", "final_url": "http://agroreal911.sk/", "lang": "sk-SK", "title": "Agroreal 911 s.r.o.", "description": "", "keywords": "", "phone_numbers": [], "links": [["http://agroreal911.sk/pozemky", "K\u00fapa p\u00f4dy"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/kontakty", "Kontakty"], ["http://www.advertplus.sk", "Advertplus.sk"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/predaj-pody", "Predaj p\u00f4dy"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/o-nas", "O n\u00e1s"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/?lang=en", ""], ["http://transposh.org/sk", ""]], "social_links": [], "emails": ["mgr.michal.hrabovsky@gmail.com"], "addresses": [], "logos": ["http://agroreal911.sk/wp-content/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/img/tplogo.png"], "text": "Agroreal 911 s.r.o. \nAGRO REAL 911,  S.R.O. \nMenu \nO n\u00e1s \nPOZEMKY \nK\u00fapa p\u00f4dy \nPredaj p\u00f4dy \nKontakty \nby  \nWebstr\u00e1nku vytvoril  Advertplus.sk Kontakt:   0908 692 782 \u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\n\n\n \n   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n   mgr.michal.hrabovsky@gmail.com\n\n\n  ", "last": 74, "n_items": 2}'
compressed=zlib.compress(line0.encode())
compressed0=compressed.replace(b"\\",b"\\\\")
compressed0=compressed.replace(b"\n",b"\\n")
print("number of line breaks in zlib output:", compressed.count(b"\n"))

def compress(str0):
  compressed=zlib.compress(str0.encode()) #encode string to binary
  compressed=compressed.replace(b"\\",b"\\\\") #doubles all backslashes
  compressed=compressed.replace(b"\n",b"\\n") #replace line breaks characters (ord: 10) with backslash (ord: 92) and letter n (ord: 110)
  return compressed

def decompress(compressed_str):
  i0=0
  decoded_array=bytearray([]) 
  while i0<len(compressed_str): #iterate over the compressed and encoded binary string character by character 
    char0=compressed_str[i0]
    if i0<len(compressed_str)-1: #to allow checking for next character
      next_char=compressed_str[i0+1]
      if char0==92: #if current character is backslasj
        if next_char==92: #and the next one is also backslash
          decoded_array.append(char0) #we return only one backslash
          i0+=1 #and jump to the character after the next
        elif next_char==110: #if the next character is the letter n
          decoded_array.append(10) #we return the linebreak character (ord: 10)
          i0+=1 #and jump to the charcter after the next
        else: decoded_array.append(char0) #otherwise just return the backslash, no jumping
      else: decoded_array.append(char0) #otherwise just return the current character, no jumping
    else: decoded_array.append(char0) #or if it's the last character, just return it
    i0+=1 #go to next character
  decoded_str=bytes(decoded_array) #get the binary string from the decoded array
  return zlib.decompress(decoded_str) #and finally decompress using zlib

compressed0=compress(line0)

test_out_fpath="test_compress.txt"
fopen0=open(test_out_fpath,"wb")
fopen0.write(compressed0)
fopen0.close()

fopen0=open(test_out_fpath,"rb")
lines=fopen0.readlines()
compressed_line=lines[0].strip(b"\n")
print("number of lines after replacing line breaks", len(lines))
decompressed=decompress(compressed_line)
print("Final decompressed", decompressed)
fopen0.close()
```

**Output**

```
number of line breaks in zlib output: 7
number of lines after replacing line breaks 1
Final decompressed b'{"symbol": "A/RES/74/1", "resolution_number": "74/1.", "title": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations: requests under Article 19 of the Charter", "session": "Seventy-fourth session", "adoption_meeting": "14th plenary meeting", "adoption_date": "2019-10-10 00:00:00", "originating_document": "A/74/483", "report_paragraph": "6", "committee": "Fifth Committee", "agenda_item": "Agenda item 139", "agenda_item_name": "Scale of assessments for the apportionment of the expenses of the United Nations", "voting_type": "Without a vote", "MS_in_favour_count": "N.A.", "MS_against_count": "N.A.", "MS_abstaining_count": "N.A.", "pv": "A/74/PV.14", "MS_in_favour": [], "MS_against": [], "MS_abstaining": [], "sponsors": ["SUBMITTED BY THE CHAIR OF THE COMMITTEE"], "additional_sponsors": [], "SDGs": [], "subjects": [["Comoros", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Sao Tome And Principe", "UNBIS Thesaurus"], ["Somalia", "UNBIS Thesaurus"]]} {"url": "http://agroreal911.sk", "final_url": "http://agroreal911.sk/", "lang": "sk-SK", "title": "Agroreal 911 s.r.o.", "description": "", "keywords": "", "phone_numbers": [], "links": [["http://agroreal911.sk/pozemky", "K\xc3\xbapa p\xc3\xb4dy"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/kontakty", "Kontakty"], ["http://www.advertplus.sk", "Advertplus.sk"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/predaj-pody", "Predaj p\xc3\xb4dy"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/o-nas", "O n\xc3\xa1s"], ["http://agroreal911.sk/?lang=en", ""], ["http://transposh.org/sk", ""]], "social_links": [], "emails": ["mgr.michal.hrabovsky@gmail.com"], "addresses": [], "logos": ["http://agroreal911.sk/wp-content/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/img/tplogo.png"], "text": "Agroreal 911 s.r.o. \nAGRO REAL 911,  S.R.O. \nMenu \nO n\xc3\xa1s \nPOZEMKY \nK\xc3\xbapa p\xc3\xb4dy \nPredaj p\xc3\xb4dy \nKontakty \nby  \nWebstr\xc3\xa1nku vytvoril  Advertplus.sk Kontakt:   0908 692 782 \xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\n\n\n \n   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n   mgr.michal.hrabovsky@gmail.com\n\n\n  ", "last": 74, "n_items": 2}'
```

Hope it will be of help.